# Is std::greater<double> and std::less<double> safe to use?

Tags: c++, double, floating-point-precision

When comparing `double` values in C++, using the `<,>,=,!=` operators, we cannot always be sure about correctness of the result. Thats why we use other techniques to compare `doubles`, for example, we can compare two doubles a and b by testing if their difference is really close to zero. My question is, does the C++ standard library implements `std::less<double>` and `std::greater<double>` using these techniques, or it just uses the unsafe comparison operators?

Comment: Note that those "more correct" techniques are incompatible with `std::set<double>`. To be compatible, `a==b && a==c` must imply `b==c`.

Comment: "difference is really close to zero" - this is working around a problem in the calculation of the values being compared. It has nothing to do with the comparison itself, which is well defined and correct. Garbage in, garbage out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can be a 100% sure about the correctness of the result of those operators. It's just that a prior calculation may have resulted in truncation because precision of a double is not endless. So the operators are perfectly fine, just your operands are not what you expected them to be.

So it does not matter what you use for comparison.

Answer (score 4):

They use standard operators. Here is the definition of std::greater in stl_function.h header file

```
  templatete<typename _Tp>
    struct greater : public binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
    {
      bool
      operator()(const _Tp& __x, const _Tp& __y) const
      { return __x > __y; }
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

`operator<` and `operator>` do give the correct result, at least as far as possible. However, there are some fundamental problems involved with using floating point arithmetics, especially `double`. These are not reduced by using the comparison functions you mention, as they are inherent to the floating point representation used by current CPUs.

As for the functions `std::less` / `std::greater`: They are just packaged versions of the standard operators, intended to be used when a binary predicate is needed in STL algorithms.

A `double` value has a 64 bit representation, whereas the Intel CPUs' original "double" arithmetic is done in 80 bits. Sounds good at first to get some more precision "for free", but it also means that the result depends on whether the compiler lets the code use intermediate results directly from the FPU registers (in 80 bits) or from the values written back to memory (rounded to 64 bit). This kind of optimization is completely up to the compiler and isn't defined by any standard.

To make things more complex, modern compilers can also make use of the newer vector instructions (MMX / SSE), which again are 64 bits only. The problems described above do not appear in this context. However, it depends on the compiler whether it makes use of these instructions for floating point arithmetics.

Comparisons for less/greater of almost equal values always will suffer when the difference is only in the last bits of the mantissa -- they are always subject to truncation errors, and you should make sure that your program does not critically rely on the result of a comparison of very close values. You can for example considering them equal when their difference is less than a threshold, e.g. by `if (fabs(a - b)/a < factor*DBL_EPSILON) { /* EQUAL */ }`. `DBL_EPSILON` is defined in `float.h`, and `factor` depends on how many mathematical operations with possible truncation/rounding have been made previously, and should be tested thoroughly. I've been safe with values around `factor=16..32`, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 3):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) it says

> Uses operator< on type T.

Meaning that unless there's an `operator<` or `operator>` you have specifically overloaded on `double` to implement proper comparison, there is going to be NO proper comparison extant for you using `std::less` or `std::greater`.

IOW you can use `std::greater` or `std::less` but it will use standard comparison unless you go implement some `operator<` or `operator>` specifically to compare `double`s or `float`s properly using their difference less than `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`

Comment: Um, "nearly equal" is an advanced technique, not at all suitable for beginners, and definitely not "proper comparison". `<` and `>` and `==` do proper comparison; any issues with the results come from the values that are passed, not from the operators. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: And even if approximate comparisons were appropriate, why would `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()` be the right tolerance to use? That is the step between representable numbers at the magnitude of 1, but the rounding errors in individual operations depend on the magnitude of the actual result involved, not of 1, and the combined errors of many operations cannot be generally predicted in any way.